Bank Alfalah Payment Gateway in Flutter: Exception Thrown Despite Success Response
I'm integrating the Bank Alfalah payment gateway in my Flutter app. I have the following code for initiating a payment request. Even when I receive a "success": true response, I'm still encountering an exception. I've tried generating the request hash using HMAC SHA-256 encryption, but my generated hash doesn't match the static hash key provided, and I'm not sure if this is causing the issue.
    int bankOrderId = Random().nextInt(1786612);
    var transactionReference = bankOrderId.toString();

    var dataString = "HS_ChannelId=$channelId&HS_IsRedirectionRequest=0"
        "&HS_MerchantId=$merchantId&HS_StoreId=$storeId"
        "&HS_ReturnURL=$returnUrl&HS_MerchantUsername=$username"
        "&HS_MerchantPassword=$password&HS_TransactionReferenceNumber=$transactionReference";

    var encryptedRequestHash = _encryptData(dataString);

    try {
      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(url),
        body: {
          // "HS_ChannelId": channelId,
          // "HS_IsRedirectionRequest": "0",
          // "HS_MerchantId": merchantId,
          // "HS_StoreId": storeId,
          // "HS_ReturnURL": returnUrl,
          // "HS_MerchantHash":
          //     "My MerchantHash",
          // "HS_MerchantUsername": username,
          // "HS_MerchantPassword": password,
          // "HS_TransactionReferenceNumber": transactionReference,
          // "HS_RequestHash": encryptedRequestHash,
          "HS_ChannelId": "My channel Id",
          "HS_MerchantId": "My Merchant Id",
          "HS_StoreId": "My Store Id",
          "HS_ReturnURL": "xyz",
          "HS_MerchantHash": "My HS_MerchantHash",
          "HS_MerchantUsername": "my username",
          "HS_MerchantPassword": "my pass",
          "HS_TransactionReferenceNumber": "12345",         "HS_RequestHash":"vU9+EdDzpTIjhxJMT4v/EfAycy/Eo6+U4wuCo0lMaf2gOz95IXHe6LdwxcVvQh7VEp2cqz32OPtJIPQlebnlVCpmCKXMOiVExLn87vq0Fd31Wm/VpyUbogHMrLoYQv23gMOpvethLE2CA39VLGDeYI98VA8wKM+ZVmLZv1QqZ3FCfkgM+ciIh8cygpa4A0zKQD7hj8x+xlSKsRY2dPrSFdPDdkUPw37ST5v7Mj7UMSvljdiBQTuY0ri9goWowpfclgpBdu1RFbOSJSr/AshY/NYCOgTC638YS1g=="
        },
      );

      // debugPrint the raw response body
      debugPrint("Response Body: ${response.body}");

      // Decode the response body as JSON
      var jsonResponse;
      try {
        jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        debugPrint("Decoded JSON Response: $jsonResponse");
        //debugPrint("Type of success: ${jsonResponse["success"]?.runtimeType}");
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint("Error decoding JSON: $e");
        throw Exception("Failed to decode JSON response: $e");
      }

      // Ensure jsonResponse is a Map and contains 'success'

      // debugPrint type of 'success' and other fields
      // debugPrint("Type of success: ${jsonResponse['success']?.runtimeType}");
      // debugPrint(
      //     "Type of AuthToken: ${jsonResponse['AuthToken']?.runtimeType}");
      // debugPrint(
      //     "Type of 'ErrorMessage': ${jsonResponse['ErrorMessage']?.runtimeType}");

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // debugPrint("Type of AuthToken: ${jsonResponse['AuthToken']}");
        // return {
        //   "authToken": jsonResponse["AuthToken"],
        // };
      } else {
        // Log the error message returned by the API
        // debugPrint("Error Message: ${jsonResponse['ErrorMessage']}");
        throw Exception(
            "Payment initiation failed: ${jsonResponse['ErrorMessage']}");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // debugPrint("Error initiating payment: $error");
      throw Exception("Error initiating payment: $error");
    }
    throw Exception();
  }

  // Encrypt data using HMAC SHA-256 with base64 encoding
  static dynamic _encryptData(var data) {
    var key = utf8.encode(key1); // Use key1 as the HMAC key
    var hmac = Hmac(sha256, key); // HMAC with SHA-256
    var digest = hmac.convert(utf8.encode(data)); // Convert data to hash
    return base64.encode(digest.bytes); // Encode hash in base64
  }```

Thanks for any guidance or insight!

